# Symbol's function definition is void: yas/initialize (emacs yasnippet)

Tags: javascript, emacs, yasnippet

I am trying to configure Emacs with [`yasnippet`](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) and a few templates for JavaScript according to [this](http://blog.deadpansincerity.com/2011/05/setting-up-emacs-as-a-javascript-editing-environment-for-fun-and-profit/) tutorial .

I am new to Emacs and I can't figure out why the `yas` function doesn't exist. The error I get is:

> Symbol's function definition is void: yas/initialize

These are the contents of my init file:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(yas/initialize)
;; Load the snippet files themselves
(yas/load-directory "~/.emacs.d/yasnippet/snippets/text-mode")
;; Let's have snippets in the auto-complete dropdown
(add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-yasnippet)
```

Comment: `yas/initialize` is obsolete. There's `yas--initialize` but you don't want that. Just see https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet for current version

Comment: I think you can just remove that line.